# Video tag javascript source

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

When using the video tag it's common to use multiple sources.

For the following code:

```
<script>    

window.onload = function() {
  if (/* conditions */ window.innerWidth >= 769) 
    document.querySelector("video").src = "https://x.com/assets/video.webm";
}

</script>
```

How do I add a backup video source ie. https://x.com/assets/video.mp4 without overwriting the previous source? In addition, how do I add the source type to each one? (ie. type="video/mp4")

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `<source>` elements as children of the `<video>` instead of simply setting the `src` attribute of the `<video>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use source tags and change their src value (check this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source).

So for example:

```
const video = document.createElement('video');
const source1 = document.createElemnent('source');
source1.src = 'https://....'
const source2 = document.createElemnent('source');
source2.src = 'https://...';
video.appendChild(source1);
video.appendChild(source2);
```

This will create video tag with two sources.